# How can I convert a folder into a sub domain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain, multisite

I have a website that looks like this (*the Ferrari is not a physical folder is an alias virtual*):

**www.example.com/en/ferrari**

and I would like to convert this site into a sub-domain, like so:

**ferrari.example.com**

or something like:

**ferrari.example.com/en/**

---

The idea is to have all sub-pages from the Ferrari section working inside the sub-domain.

I don't know if this is even possible, all my .htaccess test didn't worked out.
I am searching for a re-write rule but I don't seem to find it.

### EDIT:

Let me rephrase the question, I don't want to REDIRECT from example.com/ferrari to ferrari.example.com

What I want is to show the example.com/ferrari site when someone opens ferrari.example.com. That is the difficult part. If someone opens ford.example.com, I want to show all the pages that are inside example.com/ford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ferrari\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/ferraricars [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:en/)?(.*) en/ferraricars/$1 [NC,L]
```

Work with `ferrari.example.com/en/other` and `ferrari.example.com/other` -> `example.com/en/ferraricars/other`

Comment: As soons as I put this line: RewriteRule ^(?:en/)?(.*) en/ferrari/$1 [NC,L]

I get a 500 server error :( if I delete it it don't

Comment: Is there a misspell there or something?

Comment: It's all your .htaccess with 4 lines, or you have other rules ?

Comment: I am missing something and no I don't have any rules. :(
From reading your suggestion it should work. One more try please.
acuallty the correct url is: example.com/en/ferraricars and I want to redirect to ferrari.example.com - Can you correct your suggestion with this new urls please.

Comment: You rewrite from `ferrari.example.com` to `example.com/en/ferraricars` ! I just updated my code.

Comment: :( with this code the user will be redirect to example.com/en/ferareicars correct?

Comment: No, it's not a redirection. The user can see the page, but url don't change.

Answer (score 0):

I had faved [this link](http://www.paulund.co.uk/redirect-folder-subdomain) a year ago and it worked for me.

PS: I don't remember, and I'm not sure, but I think that I have added some other flags in the htaccess. Let me know if it not working on comments.

Comment: I have edited the question. You solution is not the correct one for me, don't you agree?

Comment: Oh ok I misunderstood the question!

Answer (score -2):

With directadmin it would be possible with creating a subdomain + hatcc redirect